# Parameterless function in #define macro causes error despite gcc -E output being correct

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, clang, c-preprocessor

I have an object to store system-wide color properties which has a huge amount of repetitive code, such as:

```
Q_PROPERTY( QColor backgroundColor MEMBER m_backgroundColor NOTIFY backgroundColorChanged )
```

followed by:

```
QColor m_backgroundColor;
signals: void backgroundColorChanged();
```

I now have hundreds of these and the object is difficult to read and modify so want to replace the above with a macro, such as:

```
#define COLOR(name) public: Q_PROPERTY( QColor name MEMBER m_##name NOTIFY name##Changed ) signals: void name##Changed(); private: QColor m_##name;
```

Followed by

```
COLOR(backgroundColor)
```

If I run gcc -E on this file it gives me exactly the output I expect:

```
public: Q_PROPERTY( QColor backgroundColor MEMBER m_backgroundColor NOTIFY backgroundColorChanged ) signals: void backgroundColorChanged(); private: QColor m_backgroundColor;
```

But when I attempt to build the project, it gives me the following error: *Error: NOTIFY signal 'backgroundColorChanged' of property 'backgroundColor' does not exist in class Colors.*

However, if I manually copy the output of gcc -E and paste it into the header file it compiles and runs with no issue.

Why would a correctly expanded macro fail to build like this and how can I fix it?

Comment: your problem is that COLOR expands into the macro, but that macro does not expand, and preprocessor moves on. So what you have is basically code that would require another pass of preprocessor

Comment: However if I remove `signals: void name##Changed();` from the COLOR macro it compiles and runs, albeit without the change signal. It appears to be the `();` that's causing the issue.

Comment: Note that the error is given by `moc`, not by GCC. Maybe a bug/limitation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no solution for this issue.

Moc parses C++ headers for signals and properties. It doesn't expand any macros, so it doesn't see your signals. You can see the code that generates this error [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/tools/moc/moc.cpp#n1605), and there is no way to disable or fool this check.

Ideally, this should be fixed in moc (it should either provide an option to bypass this check or have an ability to expand macros as the compiler does). You could use another preprocessor to expand macros to another file before passing the header to moc (this is perfectly possible if you use cmake, but I'm not sure about qmake), but I see this as overkill. I recommend you to remove signal declaration from your macro and define signals explicitly.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be the issue. Defining the signals manually works and isn't too bad a work-around.